# Rotating Text in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm working on something and seem to be stuck. I'm trying to add text over a button in Processing, however, once I use the translate method, my text is appearing upside down. How I can I simply rotate it so that it appears normal? Here's what I have:

```java
void setup(){

size(600,600);  
background(255);   
translate(20,500);  
scale(1,-1);   
line(0,0,0,475);  
line(0,0,550,0);  
fill(0,255,0);  
rect(400,-50,100,40);   
fill(0);  
font = loadFont("TimesNewRoman.vlw");  
textFont(font,24);  
rotate(PI/2);   
text("Compute",405,-30);  
}
```

Comment: could you set up the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not caused by the `translate()` function. It's caused by passing a negative value into the `scale()` function. Here's a simple program that shows your problem:

```
scale(1,-1);
text("hello", 20, -20);
```

(You should really get into the habit of testing your assumptions and trying to isolate the problem like this.)

The `scale(1, -1);` line is flipping everything vertically. I can't really imagine why you would want to do that, so the simplest option would be to get rid of that line.

If you really need your scale flipped, then you're going to have to flip it back before you draw your text.